# Optimize raid drive for disk read

Tags: ubuntu, raid, io, optimization

I have a Hardware RAID10 setup at home for my home server. I run a Plex Media server and a Nextcloud cloud server for my family at home. My concern is, that when I am downloading a movie (heavy disk write operation) I can't watch movies (heavy read operation) simultaneously.

**Is there a way to optimize the Linux driver (I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) to prioritize read first?**

Other technical details:

- [My hardware raid](https://www.raidsonic.de/products/external_cases/soho_raid/index_en.php?we_objectID=1003)
- I have 4x [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Toshiba-P300-7200RPM-SATA-HDWD130UZSVA/dp/B0151KM6F0) HDD in RAID
- The file system is ext4

Comment: You sure it's not a network issue? Usually neither of those operations are "heavy" enough to be noticeable, that plus client buffering... you can try setting a larger read ahead but it probably won't help.

Comment: You can tweak the IO scheduler with `ionice`: https://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice

Comment: @frostschutz The server never has any lags, watching movies is always smooth. The only time I experience this is when I download a movie while watching. @Emmanuel Rosa Thanks I am looking into the mq-deadline IO Scheduler parameters right now, but I will also check `ionice`